# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id on Ant

Tags: deployment, error, ant

Recently made some changes to some of objects turning some from formulas to number fields and vice versa.

I added `DestructivechangesPre.xml` to delete those fields (and in a more extreme manner, after the field deletions didn't work, the objects themselves).

That cleared out the errors around fields but I have a new error

> build.xml:56: Failed to process the request successfully.
>   Cause(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION): INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross
>   reference id

That ends on ApexClass. I made all my apex classes and triggers empty shells (only the public class) and still it shows that error.

Any thoughts on whats going on here?

```
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1352/1449)  -- Processing Type: ApexClass
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Failed (1444/1449)  -- Processing Type: ApexClass
```

Comment: Seems like you're referencing invalid field in your apex class.